# Is it possible to add a hyperlink to ASP LinkButton

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web

I have a link button that I want to put a hyperlink to that a popup div is called when the button is clicked.

The asp linkbutton is declared as such:

```
<TD Class="SpreadSheet"<ASP:LinkButtonID="lbtnViewUsers_Edit" Text="Edit" Runat="Server" onclick="#Upload"/></TD>
```

and the popup to be called is

```
<div id="Upload" class="overlay" runat="server">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>Edit User &nbsp </h2>
            <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                <div class="content">
                <!-- content -->
                </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to put a sort of `href = "#Upload"` to the link button?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  A `LinkButton` already renders as a hyperlink.  Putting a link *inside* of a link is generally a bad idea (and may be invalid entirely).  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  If the `LinkButton` posts back to the server anyway, then what do you expect to accomplish by opening a modal?  The page is going to refresh from the post back.

Comment: If all you want is open a modal, you dont need a Server Side link button you could juste use a regular <a> link

Comment: I want it to be able to open the popup when clicking on the button

Comment: LinkButton has a PostBackUrl attribute, but that will not solve your issue. Instead you can use the OnClientClick event to call your popup via javascript.

Comment: the op here is trying to do something similar hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506313/jquery-popup-from-linkbutton

Comment: @ElDj: But a `LinkButton` generates a post-back to the server.  That "popup" is going to immediately disappear when the page refreshes, doing whatever it is your server-side code is doing.  It's still not clear what your goal is here.  You're asking how to update the page *and* refresh the page at the same time.  Those are mutually exclusive things.

Comment: This is my goal: There's a table on the form which get populated from a database. On each row, there is an "Edit" button. When the edit is clicked a table with textboxes appears and allows the user to edit information on the current dataset and click on save to save everything back to the database. I'm able to display it at the bottom of the page, but my goal is to make the "edit" form appear in a popup for readability and ease of use. I hope that clears any confusion. I'm new to web development, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a model pop. Asp.net Ajax tool kit has one, you can learn more about it at [here](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.net/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) . I created a simple sample of how to use this model pop-up. Bear in mind you first have to add the tool kit to your asp.net project (you can use nuget package manager for this) and register the control to page using

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

use the properties of Model pop extender to show and save your per record data.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server" Width="400px">
    <asp:Panel ID="headerPanel" runat="server">Header text Here </asp:Panel>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="lable 1"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Text="Save" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>

<div class="form-group">
    Other data values here
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" runat="server">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```